# Android studio doesn't recognize USB devices in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I'm using ubuntu `16.04` version with Android studio `2.1.2`. I tried to run my application with Nexus 7 (Android version `5.1.1`) and Samsung GT-S6102 (Android version `2.3.6`).

Android studio doesn't recognize any device.

When I tried `/Android/Sdk/platform-tools ./adb devices`, it didn't show any devices.

what will be the issue?

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging? Tried different cables? Some cables are only for charging

Comment: USB debugging was the problem. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your udev rules, be sure you have added a rule for your Android device (using the VID/PID of the device) and your user ID.  See this page for more details:  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

You may need to use `lsusb` to get the details for the device.

Comment: `udev` rule sets permissions needed for the device to be used. But `adb devices` is able to list the device even without permissions.

Comment: No it won't, unless it is run by root. The permissions for udev are needed in order for any unprivileged user to see the devices. Running `adb devices` is still trying to talk to the devices attached in order to get the serial numbers.

Comment: obviously you have no idea what you are talking about. Older versions of `adb` used to show `????????????` instead of the serial number and recent versions just pull the serial number from `udev` database. In either case an empty `adb devices` list would indicate some problem other than device permissions.

Comment: ROFL. I'm not sure what you're trying to prove with your comment, but it made me laugh. Udev rules and permissions are critical for adb to actually communicate with the devices. I'm speaking from experience, having developed a half dozen custom Android devices and debugged on over 2 or 3 dozen different devices from different mfrs.

Comment: get off your high pony and read my comments until they make sense to you. The OP has indicated that the `adb devices` did not show any devices. Laugh all you want but your root-cause analysis was wrong. All I am trying to explain to you is that the empty `adb devices` list can not be caused by no permissions. And what is laughable is your attempt to compensate for the lack of basic comprehension by mentioning your work experience (it is not as formidable as mine anyway)

Comment: Wow. And you say that I'm on a high "pony"!  Your condescending tone is unnecessary and off-putting.  I'm not compensating for anything and am quite comfortable with my answer (though the end cause was not have debugging enabled.)  I have see the behavior before with udev setup incorrectly (or not at all.)  My reference to experience was to provide background, not try to show you up, which you continue to attempt to do with your comments back.  You are more than welcome to continue to throw insults in comments back - I'm done with it as it provides no value to the poster or future readers.